# Problemas con envio de correos en java

Tags: java, outlook

Hola amigos buenas tardes, estoy teniendo problemas con el envio de correos en java y Outlook, lo que sucede en ciertas ocasiones funciona y en otras no, por ejemplo, diariamente llega información a un servidor y lo manda a otro, solo que en determinada ocasiones cuando dichos archivo contiene información, esta información se plasma en el cuerpo del correo pero cuando llegan llenos no se mandan pero cuando el archivo viene sin información (que también está bien ya que puede o no llegar info) solamente estos si llegan correo, espero que mas o menos me pueda dar a entender, esto es el codigo para la parte de los correos:

```
public void mailSender(String sSubject, String sBody, String seccion) {
        cargaMailconf(seccion);

        if (envio.equals("0")) {
            logger.info("Prueba 4...");
            logger.warn("Envio bloqueado");
            return;
        }

        final String user = "no_reply_cfdi@mail.telcel.com";// change accordingly

        String spassword = this.password;
        String to = this.toEmail;

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", this.host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(user, spassword);
            }
        });
        logger.info("Prueba 1...");
        try {
            logger.info("Prueba 2...");
            List<String> lst = Arrays.asList(to.split(";"));

            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(user));

            for (String sCorreo : lst)
                message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(sCorreo));

            message.setSubject(sSubject);

            message.setContent(sBody, "text/html");

            // send the message
            Transport.send(message);

            logger.info("message sent successfully...");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            logger.error("Error: " + e);
            logger.info("Prueba 3...");
        }

    }

/**
 * Carga la configuracion para el envio de correos
 * 
 * @param seccion
 */
private void cargaMailconf(String seccion) {
    Configuracion conf = new Configuracion();
    Map<String, String> map = conf.confMail(seccion);

    this.envio = map.get("envio");
    this.host = map.get("host");
    // this.port = map.get("port");
    // this.fromEmail = map.get("fromEmail");
    this.password = map.get("password");
    this.toEmail = map.get("toEmail");

}



 public Boolean envioCorreoCETotales(String sSubject, String sHeader,List<String> lstProcesados,List<String> lstErrores, String seccion)    {
      Boolean benviado;
      cargaMailconf(seccion);
      
      if (envio.equals("0")) {
          logger.warn("Envio bloqueado");
          return true;
      }

      String ambiente = devAmbiente();
      sSubject = ambiente + " - " + sSubject;
      
      MailBodyBuilder mailBodyBuilder = new MailBodyBuilder();
      String sText = mailBodyBuilder.armaMailCETotales(sHeader,lstProcesados,lstErrores);
      
      try {
          
          MailSenderServer mailSenderServer = new MailSenderServer();
          mailSenderServer.mailSender(sSubject, sText, seccion);
          benviado = true;
          logger.info("Prueba 6");
      } catch (Exception e) {
          logger.error("Mail no enviado: {}", e);
          logger.info("Prueba 7");
          benviado = false;
      }
      
      return benviado;
  }


/**
 * Armado de cuerpo de correo de Envio de totales a Contabilidad Electronica
 * @param sHeader
 * @param lstProcesados
 * @param lstErrores
 * @return
 */
public String armaMailCETotales(String sHeader, List<String> lstProcesados, List<String> lstErrores) {

    final String TABLEROW = "<tr>";
    final String TABLEENDROW = "</tr>";
    final String PARRAFO = "<p>";
    final String PARRAFOEND = "<p/>";

    List<String> lstBody = pasaTabsaEspacios(lstProcesados);

    String tablas = "";
    Integer indice = 0;
    for (String body : lstBody) {

        if (!body.contains(" ")) {
            if (indice > 0) {
                tablas = tablas + "</table><br><br>";
            }
                
                tablas = tablas + "<div style=\"border: none solid #8A92DF; background-color:#DCE6F1;\">" +
                        PARRAFO +
                        "<table style=\"width:45%; border:none; border-collapse: collapse; font-family:arial;font-size:10.0pt;\">" +
                        "<tr>"  +
                        "<th bgcolor=\"#DCE6F1\" style=\"text-align: left; font-weight:lighter;\">Archivo : </th>"+    
                        "<th bgcolor=\"#DCE6F1\" style=\"text-align: right; font-weight:lighter;\">" + body + "</th>"  +  
                        "</tr></table>" +
                        PARRAFOEND +
                        "</div> <br>" +
                        "<table style=\"width:100%; border:none; font-family:arial;font-size:10.0pt;\">" +
                        "<tr>"  +
                        "<th bgcolor=\"#DCE6F1\">Regi&oacute;n</th>"+    
                        "<th bgcolor=\"#DCE6F1\">D&iacute;a</th>"  +  
                        "<th bgcolor=\"#DCE6F1\">Mes</th>"    +
                        "<th bgcolor=\"#DCE6F1\">Per&iacute;odo</th>"  +
                        "<th bgcolor=\"#DCE6F1\">Monto</th>"  +
                        "<th bgcolor=\"#DCE6F1\">Facturador</th>"  +
                        "</tr>";
        } else {
            tablas = tablas + TABLEROW + armaTdCE(body) + TABLEENDROW;

        }

        indice++;
    }
    tablas = tablas + "</table><br><br>";

    String errores = "";
    for (String cadena : lstErrores)
        errores = errores + cadena + " " + System.lineSeparator() + " ";

    if (errores.length() > 0) {

        for (String cadena : lstErrores)
            errores = errores + PARRAFO + cadena + PARRAFOEND;

        errores = PARRAFO + "Errores: " + PARRAFOEND + "<br><br>" + errores;
    }
        
    return  "<p>"+sHeader+"<p/>"+
            "<br><br>" +
            tablas     +
            "<br><br>" +
            errores +
            "<br><br>" +
            "<i>Atentamente</i>" + 
            "<br><br>" +
            "<b>Area de CFDI</b>";
 }
```

Espero y me pueda dar entender amigos, si hay algo que no se da a entender con gusto lo aclararé, Les agradezco.

Comment: Si entendí bien, el correo solo se manda cuando el archivo viene sin información.¿Tienes por casualidad los logs de cuando falla tu aplicación? ¿No se imprime ningún error? Es por lo primero que comenzaría a revisar.

Comment: Hola @JaimeMenéndez buenas tardes, en el log no se imprimen errores, de echo en ambientes previos como en desarrollo si funciona tanto con información y sin información si llegan los correos :(

Comment: O hay alguna forma para entrar a los logs del mero servidor de correos y revisar que pueda estar pasando desde ahí?